# Retrieving data from Azure Cosmosdb using user defined function through a graphql query returns null

Tags: javascript, azure, graphql, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmosdb database which has data in the below format

```
[
    {
        "partitionKey": "user",
        "userPhoneNumber": "14160000000",
        "userDisplayName": "User 1",
    },
    {
        "partitionKey": "user",
        "userPhoneNumber": "18050000000",
        "userDisplayName": "User 2",
    }
]
```

I am using the below user defined function to retrieve the matching data

```
function findUserNameByPhone(users, userPhoneNumbers) {
    var s, i, j;
    let result = [];
    for(j = 0; j < userPhoneNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) 
        {
            s = users[i];
            if(s.userPhoneNumber.match(userPhoneNumbers[j]))
                result = result.concat(s);
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

Here is how my graphql queries and resolvers are setup to call the above Azure Cosmosdb user defined function

Schema -

```
type User {
   partitionKey: String
   userPhoneNumber: String
   userDisplayName: String
   userStatus: String
   userCustomMessage: String
   avatarUrl: String
   createdAt: String # parsed to a DateTime object in Flutter
   updatedAt: String # parsed to a DateTime object in Flutter
}

type Query {
   users: [User!]!
   user(userPhoneNumber:ID!): User!
   getUsersByPhoneNumber: [User!]!
}
```

Resolver -

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: async (parent, args, { dataSources }, info) => {
       return dataSources.bolGraphQlApi.getUsers();
    },
    user: async (parent, { userPhoneNumber }, { dataSources }, info) => {
       return dataSources.bolGraphQlApi.getUser(userPhoneNumber);
    },
    getUsersByPhoneNumber: async (parent, args, { dataSources }, info) => {
       return dataSources.bolGraphQlApi.getUsersByPhoneNumber();
    }
},
```

Resolver Function

```
export class BolDataSource extends DataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getUsersByPhoneNumber = getUsersByPhoneNumber;

}
export async function getUsersByPhoneNumber() {
  const querySpec: SqlQuerySpec = {
    query: "SELECT udf.findUserByPhoneNumber(c,['14160000000','17780000000']) FROM c",
    parameters: []
  };
  const container = await initializeCosmosDb();
  const { resources: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
  return results;
};
```

I know that some parts of the code are missing here, but I can assure the other three graphql queries do work which calls the same cosmosdb data.

When I call the getUserByPhoneNumber query using the explorer of Apollo GraphQl I get null for the fields but no errors.

Please advise!

[image]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE April 6th 2023 - After trying Data API Builder

Why do I get this graphql error when I add a filter to my queries. I am not sure where to start on to fix this issue? I dont have any issues pulling up data if I don't use any filters.

Here is my query -

```
query filteritems {
    items(filter: { partitionKey: { eq: "user" } }) {
        items {
            partitionKey
            userPhoneNumber
            userDisplayName
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result -

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Access forbidden to a field referenced in the filter.",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "AuthorizationCheckFailed"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using this ? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/announcing-data-api-builder-for-azure-cosmos-db/

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. This was right on time. I also found that you have a presentation on this tomorrow. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Sure, would love to hear your feedbacks and scenarios in detail. Please reach out

Comment: @Sajeetharan Nice presentation by the way. Looking forward to more presentations on this topic. I tried the data api  builder and I was able to pull data. I do get a graphql error when I try to apply a filter on the queries, any idea what could be the reason for that. I have added more details to my post regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you open the issue on the github as well? https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/issues

Comment: @Sajeetharan Already did.